# Span tag could not make initial border at the start of paragraph

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  width: 50%;
  : #c9ffb5;
  border: 20px solid grey;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

h4{
  color: #0f4aff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

h2, p{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}


span.border{
  border-left: 5px solid grey;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="border">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer 
  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
  </span> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
  into electronic
  typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with 
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and 
  more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
  including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Trying to put the a border of left side at the start of paragraph for initial three lines. `HTML <span> tag` failed to give its effect. Border gets effect only at first line of the paragraph.

This is for putting border at specific lines in paragraph to make the attention towards reader. CSS for Zen blog could not explain neat use of span Tag. Also tried examples from W3Schools.

Comment: set to your span display:block;

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scss` and add a variable for `line-height`, then add a `:before` on the `<p>`

There is no need to include the span in this case.

You can also specify how many lines you want to include the border, by adjusting the `height` eg (`4 * $line-height`)

SCSS:

```
$line-height: 1.5em;
p {
  line-height:$line-height;

  &:before {
    content:"";
    border-left:5px solid grey;
    height: 3 * $line-height;;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
  }
}
```

[See the example](https://jsfiddle.net/53Lwyxe0/1/)

Comment: sounds bit complicated solution than `span block`. Thanks by the way.

Comment: It's not that complicated, it's a better way to use CSS and it's a more reliable solution. However, you can choose whichever answer works best for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `display:block` with `span.borders` css. It works for me

```
 span.borders{
  display:block; 
  border-left: 5px solid red;  
 padding-left: 3px; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the span is processed as one element. Simply add this to get your result:

```
span.border{
  display: inline-block;   // that one
  border-left: 5px solid grey;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: what is chip?  By the way, `display: inline-block`worked ! Thank You !

Comment: i meant "span", somehow it was a spelling mistakes from my side. Glad it worked :)

Comment: It works, but you'll need to ensure that the `<span>` always wraps the number of lines you want. This could go wrong on different devices and font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
span.border {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
span.border:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that span element have inline display by default:

```css
span {
display: inline
}
```

so to make it work you need to change span display in your css to block:

```css
span {
display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   span.border{
        display : bloack;
        border-left: 5px solid grey;
        padding-left: 3px;
    }
```